# Which statement should I use to replace custom defined function creating dummy variables to increase speed in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create several dummy variables from existing python dataframe variables. For example, column x has value from 1 to 3 and I need to create x_dummy1 which takes value 1 when x=1; 0 otherwise and x_dummy2 which takes value 1 when x=2; 0 otherwise. currently I am using custom defined functions:

```
def x_dummy(df):
    if df['x']==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
df['x_dummy1']=df.apply(x_dummy, axis=1)
```

It works well but takes a lot of time when file is large. Is there any other python statement I can use to bypass this? Thx.

Comment: Please make sure your indentation is correctly represented when transcribing Python code. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the dummy column with zeros and replace with 1's based on condition:

```
df["x_dummy1"] = 0
df.loc[df.x==1, "x_dummy1"] = 1
```